# angular, docker, nginx, Serve multiple Angular Universal apps with Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I use [this](https://github.com/ghwlchlaks/angular-universal-nginx-dockerfile) case to virtualize `angular universal` service.

But when I want to set up multiple projects there is a problem, I can't navigate to the right subpath.

For example, I hope they are set up like this:

**A service**:

`localhost/a/`
redirected
`localhost:4001/a/`

**B service**:

`localhost/b/`
redirected
`localhost:4002/b/`

I first try to set up A service:

1.set angular base href in `index.html`

`<base href="/a/">`

2.set `docker compose`

```
services:
        angular:
                container_name: angular
                build: ./angular/
                ports:
                        - '4001:4001'
                environment:
                        - PORT=4001
                networks:
                        - backend
```

3.set `nginx`

```
upstream docker-angular {
  server angular:4001;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  location /a/ {
    proxy_pass http://docker-angular;
  }
}
```

This setting is not working, angular cannot recognize path `/a/`

angular container log:

**angular    | ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'a/polyfills-es2015.f332a089ad1600448873.js'**...

I have tried different ways like only modify the `nginx location` without changing the `angular base href`.

Also tried different `nginx location` settings like:

```
location = /a/ 
location ^~ /a/
```

None succeeded.